# Mass Effect 3 Tech Combo Timings

Tags: mass-effect-3

What is the time limit between setting up a Tech with Energy Drain and Detonating with Incinerate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration of the source power, in this case Energy Drain, is the time limit.  So anytime during the duration of Energy Drain, you can use your Incinerate and setup a Tech Burst.  Since Energy Drain doesn't really have a duration, you'll likely need to have them happen simultaneously (or nearly so) in order to get the tech burst.